# How do I enforce an (Enum) interface implementation in an overridden method parameter in Java?

Tags: java, generics, parameters, enums

I'm having issues enforcing an (Enum) interface implementation as an overridden method parameter in Java. Relevant (simplified) code that shows what I'm trying to do:

```java
public interface AnimalSound {}
```

```java
public enum CowSound implements AnimalSound {
    MOO, BOO
}
```

```java
public interface Animal {
    <T extends AnimalSound> T getSound();
    <T extends AnimalSound> void setSound(T sound);
}
```

```java
public class Cow implements Animal {
    @Override
    public CowSound getSound() {
        return CowSound.BOO;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends AnimalSound> void setSound(T sound) {
        if(sound.getClass() != CowSound.class) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only works with cow sounds!");
    }
}
```

The #getSound works just fine (when I suppress the IDE Unchecked overriding warning). The #setSound however doesn't enforce a CowSound here, and I'd rather the IDE/compiler enforces this than throwing an exception during runtime.

What I -want- to do with the #setSound method is something like:

```java
@Override
public void setSound(CowSound sound) {//set a sound}
```

This however doesn't override the interface. Is there a better/other way to enforce the CowSound implementation here instead of accepting *any* implementation of AnimalSound and throw a runtime exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're making the individual methods generic, while you need to make the type generic. So, you need to use:

```
public interface Animal<T extends AnimalSound> {
    T getSound();
    void setSound(T sound);
}
```

and

```
public class Cow implements Animal<CowSound> {
    @Override
    public CowSound getSound() {
        return CowSound.BOO;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSound(CowSound sound) {
        // ...
    }
}
```